# Get currently logged-in user credentials from Active Directory using ASP

Tags: validation, asp-classic, active-directory, credentials

I would love to just use C# and be done with it, but the environment I'm working in blocks every scripting language except Active Server Pages (classic ASP). I've found several resources describing how one can validate Active Directory user credentials by querying specific username and password fields against AD. But the app I'm building will be running inside of an environment where the user's credentials have already been validated (in general) and they are already "logged in." So, I really need a way to capture the credentials of the logged-in user and compare them against a predefined list of approved user credentials (to allow special access without requiring additional login steps).

Is there any way to do this?

ASP Login example I've found: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/126267-asp-active-directory

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the user's name from the `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` server variable.

The only thing you need to ensure is that the security settings are correct on IIS.  If you're using IIS5 or 6 then you can do this by right clicking the web-site in IIS, switch to **Directory Security**, edit the authentication and access control and tick *only* the **Integrated Windows authentication** option.

In IIS 7 and above, expand to your web-site, then edit the settings under the IIS settings section, enabling only **Windows Authentication**.

Comment: This is assuming (probably stupid of me!) that you are using Windows authentication...